# How can I amend my codes to make my answer joined together to form a sentence?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying decipher a list with caesar cipher using python

ciphertext_3:  [225, 233, 228, 172, 160, 237, 249, 160, 228, 229, 225, 242, 160, 247, 225, 244, 243, 239, 238, 172, 160, 244, 232, 225, 244, 160, 237, 239, 243, 244, 160, 239, 230, 160, 249, 239, 245, 242, 160, 227, 239, 238, 227, 236]

here is my code:

```
for x in ciphertext_3:                                             
    k = chr(x-123)                                           
    answer =''.join(k)                                
    print(answer)
```

but my output is showing that the letters are not joined together and it is printing 1 letter each line instead.
[image]

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: You want to use `join` on a list containing all deciphered letters, not on each individual letter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
answer = ''
for x in ciphertext_3:                                             
    k = chr(x-123)                                           
    answer = answer + k                                
print(answer)
```